# Youtube Data API v3 different results

Tags: php, ruby, youtube, youtube-api

Very strange behavior of Youtube APi.
Results in browser and API explorer differ from results from my programmatic api call.

For example, if we try 
[https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={KEY}&maxResults=15&part=snippet&q=make+her+say&type=video&videoCategoryId=10](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=%7BKEY%7D&part=snippet%20&q=make%20her%20say) 
in browser the results will be correct and relevant.

By if I send this request from server (I tested with php file_get_contents and ruby open-uri/Net::HTTP) the results will be very strange and irrelevant.

When I simple run this query in browser, the first result is:

```
...
"title": "Kid Cudi - Make Her Say (Explicit) ft. Kanye West,Common",
...
```

But when I run this pice of code

```
<?php print file_get_contents([SAME QUERY STRING]); ?>
```

The first result is

```
   ...
   "title": "Make her Say ( Afrojack )"
   ...
```

UPDATE!
I have tested it from another server and it worked normal. So the problem is connected with our server. Maybe google have some history for our IP?
What could be the problem?

Comment: Worked for me with straight PHP. Let's see your code.

Comment: I`ve added more info and example. It is some kind of magic((

Comment: Hi, did you had a chance to get this problem solved on your original server? any suggestions? having the same issue..